# Proper way to update state in nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using a few different technologies in a self learning project (reddit clone):

- react
- react-redux
- redux
- react-router (v4)

Goal: When clicking on an edit link to a post, go to proper route with edit form fields populated.

I am using a container that dispatches an action and re-renders updating the component inside the containers props. It looks like this:

CONTAINER:

```
class PostContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {  
    debugger;
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPost(id));
  }
  render() {  
    return (

      <Post post={this.props.post} editing={this.props.location.state? this.props.location.state.editing : false}/>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  debugger;
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    post: state.post
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(PostContainer));
```

The nested Post component has additional nested components:

POST Component:

```
class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.editToggle = this.editToggle.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    editing: this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.editing : false
  };

  editToggle() {
    this.setState({editing: !this.state.editing});
  }

  render() {
    const {editing} = this.state;
    if (editing || this.props.post === undefined) {    
      return <PostEditForm  editToggle={this.editToggle} editing={this.props.editing} post={this.props.post || {}}/>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
      <div>
       <h2>Title: {this.props.post.title}</h2>
       <span>Author: {this.props.post.author}</span>
       <br/>
       <span>Posted: {distanceInWordsToNow(this.props.post.timestamp)} ago f</span>

       <p>Body: {this.props.post.body}</p>
       <button type='button' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => this.editToggle()}>Make Edit</button>
     </div>
     <hr/>
     <Comments post={this.props.post}></Comments>

     </div>

    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Post);
```

**In the `render` function within the first `if` statement, I pass the updated props to `<PostEditForm>`. When PostEditForm receives the props, it re-renders the component, but the state of the component is not updated.**

PostEditForm:

```
class PostEditForm extends Component {

  state = {
    timestamp: this.props.post.timestamp || Date.now(),
    editing: this.props.editing || false,
    body: this.props.post.body || '',
    title: this.props.post.title || '',
    category: this.props.post.category || '',
    author: this.props.post.author || '',
    id: this.props.post.id || uuid()

  };

  clearFormInfo = () => {
    this.setState({
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      body: '',
      title: '',
      category: '',
      author: '',
      id: uuid(),
      editing: false
    });
  };

  handleOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const post = {
      ...this.state
    };

    if(this.state.editing) {
      this.props.dispatch(updatePostAPI(post));
      this.setState({
        editing: false
      })
    } else {
      this.props.dispatch(createPostAPI(post));
      this.clearFormInfo();
      window.location.href = `/${post.category}/${post.id}`;
    }    
  };
  render() {

    const {editing} = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <h2>Create New Post</h2>
          <label htmlFor='text'>
            Title:
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              value={this.state.title}
              placeholder="Enter Title"
              required
              id="title"
              name="title"
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Author:
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              value={this.state.author}
              placeholder="Enter Author"
              required
              id="author"
              name="author"
            />
          </label>
          <label>

          </label>
          <label>
            Body:
            <textarea
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              value={this.state.body}
              placeholder="Enter Body"
              required
              id="body"
              name="body"
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <label>
        Category:

        <select id = 'category' onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.value} required>
          <option value='Select Category'>Select Category</option>
          <option value='react'>react</option>
          <option value='redux'>redux</option>
          <option value='udacity'>udacity</option>
        </select>

        </label>
      <button type='submit'>Create Post</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


export default connect()(PostEditForm);
```

I believe I need to call `setState` and assign the new props passed into the state, but I don't know which lifeCycle method to use.

When I use `componentDidUpdate`, something like:

```
class PostEditForm extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    if(this.props.post.id !== prevProps.post.id) {
      this.setState({
        timestamp: this.props.post.timestamp,
        editing: this.props.post.editing,
        title: this.props.post.title,
        category: this.props.post.category,
        author: this.props.post.author,
        id: this.props.post.id
      })
    }
  }
 .....
```

`componentDidUpdate` solves the initial problem, but whenever I update content in the form I am editing, the lifeclycle method is called, eliminating the need for the onChange handlers, is this a good practice or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

just a note

`componentDidUdpate` is called after every re-render,

`componentDidMount` is called after the instantiation of the component.

if you modify your state inside the `componentDidUdpate()` hook you will end up in an infinite loop since a `setState()` will retrigger the `render()` and consequently the `componentDidUpdate()`

if you modify your state in the `componentDidMount()` this hook is called only once, after instantiation, not every re-render thus it won't work as well for subsequent updates.

However the problem lays here:

```
state = {
    timestamp: this.props.post.timestamp || Date.now(),
    editing: this.props.editing || false,
    body: this.props.post.body || '',
    title: this.props.post.title || '',
    category: this.props.post.category || '',
    author: this.props.post.author || '',
    id: this.props.post.id || uuid()

  };

render() {

    const {editing} = this.state;
    //change to const {editing} = this.props;
    ....
}
```

the way you're declaring the state won't work for future updates, state will point to the values of the props once the instantion is done, just primitive values that are immutable for definition.

you should just refer to `this.props` across the whole `PostEditForm` `render()` method instead of `this.state` and you should be fine.

to update the state you should pass a callback to PostEditForm from the parent (in this case Post component) and trigger it when needed.

And regarding the default values i'd suggest the use of Proptypes library.

something like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
class PostEditForm extends Component {
   //your business logic
}

PostEditForm.propTypes = {
  timestamp: Proptypes.Object,
  editing: PropTypes.bool,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  category: PropTypes.string,
  author: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string
}
PostEditForm.defaultProps = {
 timestamp: Date.now(),
 editing: false,
 body: '',
 title: '',
 category: '',
 author: '',
 id: uuid()
}
```